# CPQ - Set Contracted True too soon does not create contract

Tags: visual-workflow, cpq, contracts

we're developing a flow that takes an order, activates it and then automatically flag
**SBQQ__Contracted__c = True**.
In my mind CPQ should create a contract but in reality if i launch it syncronously it doesn't, i see the flag contracted but without a related contract.
The only way I found is to stop the flow, wait few min and then set Contracted=True
If I wait at least one minute then the contract gets created, I just dont' understand why this happens only with this functionality.
Is there a way to make everything in just one syncronous flow?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The order products need time to update to Activated before they can be contracted.